# Error deploying windows phone app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8

I get the following error when deploying my app:

Event handler 'Input_TextChanged' not found on class 'Program.MainPage'

What happened and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your MainPage.xaml code you probably have something like this:

```
<TextBox TextChanged="Input_TextChanged" />
```

But no handler for this in your MainPage.xaml.cs code, which should look like this:

```
private void Input_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

So either you remove `TextChanged="Input_TextChanged"` from your XAML or add the event handler to the code-behind file.